# ADFS, iOS, and certificates

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, adfs, azure-ad-msal

I'm using the MSAL framework in an iOS app. It's all works well when I authenticate against our inside ADFS server that only needs username/password. The public facing server requires a client certificate. From the public Internet, when I hit the Graph API without a token, I get redirected to a page that says a certificate is required and to select one to use. There is nothing to select and I can't do anything other than exit at that point. I see the same behavior with MacOS and Safari. Am I missing something or should this work?

Comment: Do you get this experience in Windows too?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it today.  IE on Windows 7, login.microsoftonline.com. Same behavior. The page says to select a certificate but no list is presented. So my problem has nothing to do with Graph or MSAL.

Comment: Do you know if your Admins have set Device Based Conditional Access on? If you use a Fiddler trace, do you ever see the host `device.login.microsoftonline.com`?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not 100% sure. I didn't use Fiddler, but the network log in Chrome doesn't show any connections to device.login.microsoftonline.com.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a problem with Graph or MSAL, itself, but something configured in your tenant? Do you a have a Dev tenant that you could test this app with and rule that out?